Question about a limit of the euler-product of the riemann zeta function
The limit $$\lim_{s\to 1} (s-1)\zeta(s)=1=\lim_{s\to 1}(s-1)\prod_{p\in\mathbb P} (1-p^{-s})^{-1}$$
is well-known.
Consider that there are infinitely many distinct subsets $\mathbb P_{k}\subsetneq\mathbb P$  of the set of primes, which contain infinitely many primes, such that $\cup_{k\in\mathbb N}\mathbb P_{k}=\mathbb P$ and $\cap_{k\in\mathbb N}\mathbb P_{k}=\emptyset$.
If there is a choice of these distinct subsets, such that (for fixed k) the infinite product converges to
$$\prod_{p\in\mathbb P_{k}} (1-p^{-1})^{-1}=(1-p_{k}^{-1})^{-1},       $$
then
$$\lim_{s\to 1}(s-1)\prod_{k\in \mathbb N}\prod_{p\in\mathbb P_{k}}(1-p^{-s})^{-1}=\lim_{s\to 1}(s-1)\prod_{k\in\mathbb N}(1-p_{k}^{-s})^{-1}=\lim_{s\to 1} (s-1)\zeta(s).$$
This seems a little odd to me. Did I miss something?
Motivation: At $s_{0}\approx3.17124$, $$\pi^{s_{0}/2}=2(s_{0}-1)\Gamma(s_{0}/2+1) \iff  2\xi(s_0)=\zeta(s_0),$$ so that the euler-product (product over primes $p$) equals the hadamard product (product over non-trivial zeros $\rho_0$ of $\zeta$)  $$\prod_{p}(1-p^{-s_0})^{-1}=\prod_{\rho_{0}}(1-s_0/\rho_{0})(1-s_0/(1-\rho_{0}))$$
Assuming RV is true, one can write
$$\prod_{p}(1-p^{-s_0})^{-1}=\prod_{\rho_{0}}(1+s_0(s_0-1)/|\rho_{0}|^2).$$
At this point, it seems possible, that there exists distinct infinite subsets of the set of non-trivial zeros of $\zeta$, so that
the partial product of all these zeros of such a subset converges to a factor of the euler-product.
Numerical investigations don't help, cause the hadamard product converges too slowly.

What is $p_k$ and is it prime and what exactly seems odd to you?

$p_{k}$ is the k-th prime and it seems odd, that an infinite partial product converges to a factor of the euler-product.

How do you construct the partition $(\mathbb P_k)$ ? Its existence is not so obvious

Yeah of course! I just want to know, whether there is an argument against the existence of such subsets.

In the case of non-trivial zeros of $\zeta$, such a construction of subsets is hopeless. Anyway I was fascinated about the possibility of a "self-similar" factorisation.

If RH is true, ζ is universal in the critical strip, that means, ζ approximates every holomorphic function and so it approximates ζ itself.
